# A tool for browsing accessibility tree of an application

Tags: accessibility, msaa

I have been making scripts for screen readers (e.g. JAWS) and often have to dig into its window hierarchy (MSAA, UIA etc). I usually use the old AccExplorer32 app, but it is not optimal (the hierarchy usually does not correspond to the one generated by screen readers, plus search in the tree is very limited). Is there a better app for browsing accessibility hierarchies? It should:

- have good search capabilities (ideally you could search all accessibility fields)

  generate windows trees as close to those used by screen readers and especially JAWS as possible

  have most of other features of AccExplorer, especially the option for highlighting selected object is important

These apps are not good enough (not better for my purposes than AccExplorer): AccChecker, Process Monitor, uiaverify, spyxx. I could not find anything better, which seems strange, since there certainly is space for such an app.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I haven't used it, but have you looked at the Inspect tool? For more info on it see
http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/dd318521%28v=vs.85%29.aspx

Comment: I will check it out, thanks. It is definitely worth looking at. Now why did I miss it...

Comment: AccExplorer and Inspect 32 are the only ones I know

Comment: Well, I guess this is the best tool I have used so far. The only drawback is no search (but in AccExplorer the search is so limited that it's in fact useless)

Answer (score 1):

Have you tried the [aViewer from the Paciello Group?](http://www.paciellogroup.com/resources/aviewer) (Windows only)

Or the [DOM Inspector for Firefox](https://addons.mozilla.org/en-US/firefox/addon/dom-inspector-6622/)? (All platforms)

Both tools will show you the Accessibility Tree as rendered.

Comment: I am looking for accessibility trees of applications, not only web pages

Comment: Ahh.. well I just found a sweet looking option for OSX via Xcode: https://developer.apple.com/library/mac/documentation/Accessibility/Conceptual/AccessibilityMacOSX/OSXAXTesting/OSXAXTestingApps.html#//apple_ref/doc/uid/TP40001078-CH210-TPXREF101